# Under what circumstances React class component will be constructed many times?

Tags: reactjs

In most cases, a React class component will be constructed only once. But sometimes I met the React class component can be constructed more than once.

Then I remove the React class component from DOM, then React class component will be constructed many times.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking...when a specific page is loaded, the constructor will be called for each of the class components once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a component to be rendered, the constructor must be called to create an instance of its backing class. This only needs to be done once, before the first render.

If your component is added, then removed, then added again, the constructor will be called twice. The class corresponding to the second component is new, and separate to the first class.

Below is an example of a component that shows or hides its children. Each time the child is shown, the constructor is called, as you can see in the console.

```js
class ShowHide extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isChildShown: true
    };
    
    this.toggleChild = this.toggleChild.bind(this);
  }
  
  toggleChild() {
    this.setState({
      isChildShown: !this.state.isChildShown
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.toggleChild}>toggle</button>
      {this.state.isChildShown ? this.props.children : null}
    </div>;
  }
}

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("constructor called");
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ShowHide><TestComponent/></ShowHide>,
  document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```